# Translation operator and parity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, hamiltonian

(This is taken from *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by D. Griffiths, 3rd edition, [Problem 6.18](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/problem-618-consider-free-particle-one-dimension-h-2m-hamiltonian-translational-symmetry-i-q33521444) .)

If a system has inverse symmetry, we know that [$\hat{H},\hat{\Pi}] =0$ where $\hat{\Pi}$ is the parity operator.

This means that eigenstates of the parity operator are eigenstates of $\hat{H}$. Namely:

$f(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \hbar} }\cos(px/\hbar)$

$g(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \hbar} }\sin(px/\hbar)$

This is easily seen by doing $\hat{\Pi} f(x) =f(x) $ and $\hat{\Pi} g(x) = -g(x) $.

The problem says that translation operator mixes these two states together, meaning that they must be degenerate.

**Question**

Show that the translation operator mixes these two states together (f and g), meaning that they must be degenerate.

This is what I did:

Translation operator:  $\hat{T}u(x) = u(x-a)$
$$\hat{T}f(x)=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \hbar} }\cos(pa/\hbar)\cos(px/\hbar) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \hbar} }\sin(pa/\hbar)\sin(px/\hbar) \\ = \cos(pa/\hbar)f(x)- \sin(pa/\hbar)g(x). $$

I can see that the states are mixed. But it doesn't have the same energy as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. If I do $\hat{H}\hat{T}f(x) = E_n( \cos(pa/\hbar)f(x)- \sin(pa/\hbar)g(x)  )$

The eigenvalue $E_n$ is multiplied by a constant. The only way this is true if I say that $E_n( \cos(pa/\hbar)f(x)- \sin(pa/\hbar)g(x) ) = E_n w(x) $.

Couldn't I show that they are degenerate by using the simple fact that $\hat{H} f(x) = E_n f(x) $ and $\hat{H} g(x) = E_n g(x) $, because [$\hat{H},\hat{\Pi}] =0$ ?

Comment: You're mixing notation here quite a bit, equating vectors in Hilbert spaces to functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can you fix that to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: @CuriousHegemon Ok, I think it is clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: can you exactly type the question it is impossible to get what you are asking

Comment: @physshyp I edited it. Sorry, it was indeed confusing.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes. It is a sine. I edited it. I mistyped it.

Comment: can you just word by word retype the question in grifiths

Comment: @physshyp I added the link of the problem. I found it online.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495980/generator-for-parity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Couldn't I show that they are degenerate by using the simple fact that $\hat{H} f(x) = E_n f(x) $ and $\hat{H} g(x) = E_n f(x) $, because [$\hat{H},\hat{\Pi}] =0$ ?

Where did this come from? $\hat{\Pi}$ does not mix *f* with *g*; in fact, it keeps them visibly apart and separate.

The problem asks you to assume separate $E_f$ and $E_g$ for *f* and *g*, respectively, and use
$$
\hat{H}(\hat{T}f(x)) =  \hat{T} \hat{H} f(x)  =   E_f (\hat{T} f(x) ), 
$$
which reads explicitly as
$$
\hat{H}( \cos(pa/\hbar)f(x)- \sin(pa/\hbar)g(x) )=E_f( \cos(pa/\hbar)f(x)- \sin(pa/\hbar)g(x) )~~~\leadsto \\
- \sin(pa/\hbar)\hat{H}g(x)= - \sin(pa/\hbar) E_f~g(x),~~~~ \leadsto ~~~~E_f=E_g.
$$

Comment: My mistake. I meant: Couldn't I show that they are degenerate by using the simple fact that $\hat{H} f(x) = E_n f(x) $ and $\hat{H} g(x) = E_n g(x) $, because [$\hat{H},\hat{\Pi}] =0$ ?" g(x) anf f(x) are eigenstates of parity operator. Which means that they are eigenstates of Hamiltonian. What mixes the states together is the translation operator, just like you showed, you have $E_f ( \cos (pa/\hbar) f(x) -\sin (pa/\hbar) g(x))$.
But you are already assuming that Hg(x) = E_f g(x) and H f(x) = E_f f(x), which means that f(x) and g(x) are degenerate à priori.

Comment: We are not on the same page. Parity commuting with the hamiltonian means that parity eigenstates may be energy eigenstates, but you know nothing about how the energies of *f* and *g* are related. I *proved*, did not assume !, $ \hat Hg(x) = E_f g(x)$!! You misunderstood the proof?

Comment: I understood now! Thanks!  My problem was assuming that eigenvalues for both functions  were the same.

Answer (score 1):

I dont get the question but from what I get you have the following let

$P$ is parity operator $T$ is translation operator and let
$$[T,H]=[P,H]=0$$ also let

so we have
$$T|\alpha\rangle=|\beta\rangle$$
$$P|\alpha\rangle=|\gamma\rangle$$
also
all those three have same energy since  $T$ and $P$ commutes with hamiltonian.
now we have
$$[T,P]=C$$ c is some operator which is not important

now  $$\langle\alpha| TP|\alpha\rangle\neq\langle\alpha| PT|\alpha\rangle=\langle\alpha| TP|\alpha\rangle+\langle\alpha| C|\alpha\rangle\neq1$$ thus $\gamma$ $\beta$ states are different states with same energy thus here is your degeneracy.
here the idea is to show hamiltonian has **different** eigen states with same energy. and party with translation enforces it.

Comment: But this doesn't show that the translation operator mix those states (f and g) together, does it?. I thought the idea was to show that if you have the given f and g states that are even or odd under parity, when you apply a translation to one of these states, you will get a state that is a  mix of f(x) and g(x). This "mixed" state has the same energy as f(x) and g(x).